# Silicon Works Multi-touch Device, VID:PID 29bd:4101

Tags: linux, multi-touch, touchscreen

I have a POS terminal (APEXA G from POSBank) that comes with multi-touch screen made by Silicon Works.  The touch works perfectly on Windows there are official drivers for it. But for Linux the touch does not work at all. After inspecting the device on Linux Ubuntu distribution using [lsusb -v] command I get the follow information:
Silicon Works Multi-touch Device, VID:PID 29bd:4101
The touchscreen is connected through usb not serial connection.

I tried several generic drivers online but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

After emailing POSBank technical support I received their quick response which solves my problem.

Following their instructions here is what I did:
 1. Uninstall the old touch drivers:
    - Lanuch Device Manager
    - Human Interface Device -> Usb Input Device
    - Remove a USB input device with a value of VID_29BD in the attribute (PID is 3711 or 4101)
 2. install latest drivers chipset, LAN, touch, etc... (These drivers downloaded from POSBank official website)

-------------------------------------------------
Please note:
 -You need Windows only to run the software that applies the touch firmware upgrade.
 -Touch firmware v1.8 is still not available from POSBank official website yet
      you have to contact technical support or email me. 
 -You Must Install SiW Daemon Control Panel to upgrade the firmware (it is included in the touch driver zip file from POSBank official website)
-------------------------------------------------

3. upgrade the touch firmware to V1.8 using instructions below:

   - Open SiW Daemon Control Panel
   - On device tab press F6
   - Select Multi-touch device 0
   - Click File open then select the firmware update file
   - Click FW update

After Ubuntu boots the touch should start working out of the box no special configuration is needed.

Note: After the upgrade the touch may not work on Windows. Don't Panic. You will hear a beeping sound every time you click on the screen which is a good sign. To fix  do the following:

1. Open SiW Daemon Control Panel on the Device tap
2. select Multi-touch Device_0 then click Open Device
3. select Mouse table(2nd tap) and check Emulation Mode
4. select About tab and click Preserve Settings which preserves the settings through Windows restarts.

If you have any questions please let me know.

I am happy with their solution now touch works for me on Windows and Ubuntu.

Thank you POSBank and special thanks to Peter Kim from the technical support.